# Querying the order_product_options given the order_product_id in OpenCart

Tags: mysql, opencart

Given the condition that an order has been created and that the order has a product, there will always be (an) `order_product`(s) associated with each order. Since each product have modifiers called "options" in OpenCart (say, a shirt has S, M, X, XL), and each `order_product` have their unique `order_product_options`, I would like to generate a query that returns the `order_product_options`.

There is quite a distinction from getting the `product_option` from a `product` (not what I want to achieve), since getting the product options of a product simply returns all the modifiers of a product, and is not specific to an order's product.

When you perform this query: `select * from oc_order_product;`, you receive a table that lists all the products of an order denoted by the primary key `order_product_id`.

**My goal is to get the `order_product_options` using the `order_product_id`, however, my attempts have so far failed.** Looking at my DB using `show tables`, I do not see a table called `oc_order_product_option`, and only `oc_order_option`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I adapted Jay's answer to write this query:

```
private function getModifyByOrderProductId(
        $order_product_id
    )
    {
        $query = $this->db->query(
            "SELECT oo.product_option_id as id, " .
            "oo.name as name " .
            "FROM oc_order_option oo " .
            "JOIN oc_order_product op " .
            "ON (oo.order_product_id = op.order_product_id) " .
            "WHERE op.order_product_id = " . $order_product_id .
            ";"
        );
        return $query->rows;
    }
```

Returns the `id` and `name` of an order product's options by `order_product_id` since each order_product can have its own unique modifies/options.

Answer (score 3):

You simply need to join three tables together. The `order`, `order_product` and `order_option` tables

```
SELECT *
FROM `order` `o`
LEFT JOIN `order_product` `op`
ON `o`.`order_id` = `op`.`order_id`
LEFT JOIN `order_option` `oo`
ON `oo`.`order_product_id` = `op`.`order_product_id`
WHERE `order_id` = 12345
```

If you don't need the order product, just the options you can skip the `order_product` table completely and just use

```
SELECT *
FROM `order` `o`
LEFT JOIN `order_option` `oo`
ON `oo`.`order_id` = `o`.`order_id`
WHERE `order_id` = 12345
```